# Unit testing Symfony callback

Tags: validation, unit-testing, symfony, callback, phpunit

Hi need some help with uniting testing a Symfony 2.8 callback.
I don't think I have set it up correctly as the test is passing when I know it should be failing

The entity setup:

The validate callback in the Contact entity:

```
 /**
 * Validation callback for contact
 * @param \AppBundle\Entity\Contact $object
 * @param ExecutionContextInterface $context
 */
public static function validate(Contact $object, ExecutionContextInterface $context)
{
    /**
     * Check if the country code is valid
     */
    if ($object->isValidCountryCode() === false) {
        $context->buildViolation('Cannot register in that country')
                ->atPath('country')
                ->addViolation();
    }
}
```

The method isValidCountryCode in Contact entity:

```
/**
 * Get a list of invalid country codes
 * @return array Collection of invalid country codes
 */
public function getInvalidCountryCodes()
{
    return array('IS');
}
```

The method that checks if the country code is invalid:

```
/**
 * Check if the country code is valid
 * @return boolean
 */
public function isValidCountryCode()
{
    $invalidCountryCodes = $this->getInvalidCountryCodes();
    if (in_array($this->getCountry()->getCode(), $invalidCountryCodes)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

The validation.yml

```
AppBundle\Entity\Contact:
properties:
    //...

    country:
        //..
        - Callback: 
            callback: [ AppBundle\Entity\Contact, validate ]
            groups: [ "AppBundle" ]
```

The test class:

```
//..
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Validation;

class CountryTest extends WebTestCase
{
  //...

public function testValidate()
{
    $country = new Country();
    $country->setCode('IS');

    $contact = new Contact();
    $contact->setCountry($country);

    $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->getValidator();

    $errors = $validator->validate($contact);

    $this->assertEquals(1, count($errors));
}
```

This test returns `$errors` with a count of 0 but it should be 1 as the country code 'IS' is invalid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First** problem is about the definition of the constraint in the yml files: you need to put the [callback](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Callback.html#configuration) under the `constraint` section instead of `properties`, so change the validation.yml files as follow:

<kbd>validation.yml</kbd>

```
AppBundle\Entity\Contact:
    constraints:
       - Callback:
            callback: [ AppBundle\Entity\Contact, validate ]
            groups: [ "AppBundle" ]
```

**Second** in the testCase: you need to take the validator service from the container instead of create a new one with the builder: this object is not initializated with the object structure ect.

**Third** The callback constraints is defined for the `AppBundle` validation group only, so pass the validation group to the validator service (As third argument of the service).

So change the testClass as follow:

```
    public function testValidate()
    {
        $country = new Country();
        $country->setCode('IS');

        $contact = new Contact();
        $contact->setCountry($country);

//        $validator = Validation::createValidatorBuilder()->getValidator();
        $validator = $this->createClient()->getContainer()->get('validator');

        $errors = $validator->validate($contact, null, ['AppBundle']);
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($errors));
    }
```

And the testcase became green.

Hope this help

Comment: Sadly this isn't working either. Passing the groups as the second argument is returning deprecation warnings:            `
The "deep" option for the Valid constraint is deprecated since version 2.5 and will be removed in 3.0. When traversing arrays, nested arrays are always traversed. When traversing nested objects, their traversal strategy is used:
The Symfony\Component\Validator\ValidatorInterface::validate method is deprecated in version 2.5 and will be removed in version 3.0. Use the Symfony\Component\Validator\Validator\ValidatorInterface::validate method instead`